# How can I wait for a file to be uploaded (via ftp), then delete it?

Tags: python

Using Python, how can I wait for a file to be uploaded (using ftp) before deleting it?

```
uploadFile(ftp, filepath,namef)
# ............Here, I need to wait........
os.remove(filepath)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve and what problem did you run into that's making you try this.

Comment: It seems clear to me that the OP is trying to move a file off their computer, and then delete it when the transfer successfully completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html) to upload the file. The link I provided has many great examples for uploading files using FTP.

Use [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).remove to delete the local file.

Answer (score 2):

Using the ftplib as linked by Randolpho, it looks like you want to use:

```
FTP.storbinary(command, file[, blocksize, callback])
```

Before you transfer the file, calculate how many blocks (of size `blocksize` it will take to transfer the file.  Your callback function can count the number of times it is called and when the counter reaches the number of blocks, you know that the entire file has been transferred.  Your callback function can then call the function that deletes the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a MD5 checksum, upload it, then download it, compare the MD5, and then delete if you have a match.
Bonus: if your server supports MD5 as a site extension, you don't have to download, you can just ask the server for the MD5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function to check upload progress

```
import ftplib

ftp_uploadcomplete = False
ftp_blocksize = 1024
size_written = 0
total_size = len(myimg)

def handle(block):
    global size_written
    global total_size
    global ftp_blocksize
    size_written = size_written + ftp_blocksize if size_written + ftp_blocksize < total_size else total_size
    percent_complete = size_written / total_size * 100
    if (size_written==total_size):
        ftp_uploadcomplete = True
    print("%s percent complete" %str(percent_complete))

myftp = ftplib.FTP('host','login','pw')
myftp.storbinary("STOR file.jpg", myimg, callback=handle, blocksize=ftp_blocksize)

while (ftp_uploadcomplete==False):
    time.sleep(1)

print("Upload Done!")
```